# Editing Another Users Answer

Tags: support

Under what circumstances can a user change another user's answer?  I posted something yesterday and when I came back today there were several (largely unnecessary) changes to my answer.  It was basically reformatted to suit the others user's posting/writing style.  As far as I can tell they aren't suggestions or in any kind of pending state but have actually been published.

Comment: See http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit for some initial information;

Comment: Thanks, quid.  That was helpful.  Can you tell me what the social convention is with respect to my reverting the other user's changes back?  The changes made were largely cosmetic, i.e. substituting his writing style for mine.

Comment: I recommend in addition to flag the post for moderator attention.  If the moderator edited it, there probably was a good reason and they may tell you so.  If there is actually a problem with the edits (e.g. emphasis was changed away from what was intended), try to make a good case for changing it back first.  In some cases it is not worth the trouble, but often you should let the moderators know of your objections.  The social convention should be to ask questions (and get answers) first before shooting, which you are doing.  Gerhard "Rollback: Next To Last Resort" Paseman, 2015.09.29

Comment: If your post is in regard to this answer to this question ( http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9679 ), I would say that that user's intent is usually to improve questions without changing their thrust.  In this particular case, I recommend accepting that users changes and moving on.  However, if you see something wrong, go ahead and let the moderators know.  Gerhard "Prepare Having Your Copy Edited" Paseman, 2015.09.29

Comment: You are welcome. I added an answer, trying to address your question on etiquette of reverting. As said, it is alright to do it, if you are really not happy with the change. For the specific case, it seems to me a main goal of the edit was just trying to be helpful in reformatting the link using the mark-up common on this site (and to add an additional link). If I may make a suggestion: perhaps let it sit for a day and look at it again then, if you really do not like it then, change it.

Comment: (I've just seen this now.) Here are three brief comments: (1) I primarily edited the post in order to include a general link to the OpenCourseWare initiative, and to re-package [what I viewed as] an unwieldy URL pasted at the end of your answer [this is summarized in my brief reason for the edit: *put in hyperlinks*]; (2) @quid's answer below is an accurate reflection of my views on editing and its role on [ME]SE; (3) with regard to reverting changes / social conventions [here, I speak for myself, specifically]: please do not hesitate to revert any of my edits if you feel they are not helpful!

Comment: ...for completeness, I add: (A) I am resisting the urge even now to edit this post -- the title is missing an apostrophe: *User's* -- as it seems too *minor*; (B) I left a [**comment**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9701/simpler-explanation-for-finding-the-vertex-of-a-parabola/9714#comment20564_9714) (before seeing this thread) on another of your answers because I thought/think it would benefit from add'l algebraic details -- however, I did not edit them in because that change seemed too *major*. [It is a fine line!]

Answer (score 2):

While most individual posts have their author's name attached to them, the site is mainly to be seen as a community created and curated resource. As a consequence of this experienced users get the [ability to edit others' posts](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).
And, they do not only get the ability they are also encourage to use it; for example, it is a feature of the site that new users' posts are specifically presented to experienced users. 
The editing privilege is attained at 1000 points on this site (as the site is in beta, on graduated sites it is 2000). Users below this threshold can still suggest edits; these are reviewed by experienced users and/or the author of the post before they take effect. More details can be found under the link above.

That being said, usually editors will strive not to change the author's intent and will usually limit themselves to minor modifications. These could be, for example:

- Corrections of typos and oversights.
- Fixing broken links.
- Helping with the usage of the site's mark-up language.

If an author is not happy with an edit (in total or in part) they always have the ability to modify the post again, via another edit or also via a rollback; the link in the middle at the end of an edited post will lead on  to the posts revision history with all prior versions, and clicking a "rollback" link will take the post to that version.

To do so is also fine, just like editing is fine. Yet, neither should be done only to make a point. The common goal should be to have as good posts as possible. Thus, a good approach can be to try to look at the post with the eyes of a third-party and to see which version they might prefer.

If ever a conflict of a back-and-forth of edits should arise, please, do not escalate and "fight an edit-war" over many versions. Instead just leave it for a while and flag for a moderator: "flag" then "other" and describe the concern.

Finally, let me mention that in case it is needed to clear-up something, there is the possibility to contact an editor with the usual `@user` syntax (even though auto-complete does not propose it).